# catch objective-c loadRequest loading blank page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How would one catch loadRequest returning a 404 page,

i am calling the load request like so:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:qype_url]]];
```

can't seem to figure out how to catch what it returns so i can deal with this situation and load an error page. If the url is incorrect a blank page is returned for example: http://i.qype.co.uk/place/2535934 but how do i catch this in my code? thanks!

Comment: UIWebView gives you a way to listen for requests starting to load, but not finishing per se...

Comment: webViewDidFinishLoad is called even if it has returned an empty html document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen for

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

part of `UIWebViewDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for catching pages such as 404's which do not fire the didFailLoadWithError method.

```
- (SCNetworkReachabilityRef)reachabilityRefForHostName:(NSString *)hostName
```

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html